# Issue with System.EnterpriseServices trying to connect to Oracle DB

Tags: oracle, vb.net

I used VS2019 on Windows 10 64.

In a .NET Winform application (using .NET v5 framework), I'd like to interact with Oracle DB which is running on a distant server.

So, I installed SQL Developper, Oracle Client in C:\App\db_home. SQL Developper works fine and can access to the Oracle DB perfectly.

I add to my VS Project the reference which seems to be the good one (pretty hesistating on that part but "trying is the way to success") : C:\App\db_home\ODP.NET\bin\4\Oracle.DataAccess.dll
Everything seems ok:
[image: References List of my project]

Here's my code to get the connection working (the italic text was edited for posting this online)

```
Public Function OpenOracleBddConnexion()
        Dim  Public strOracleConnection As String = "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=*Host_URL*)(PORT=*DB_Port*))) (CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=*SERVICE_NAME*))); User Id=*USER_ID*;Password=*User_ID*;"
        Dim strMsgException As String = "Problème de connexion aux bases Oracles. " & strMsgErrorTellYourAdmin & vbCrLf & "-- Message d'erreur: "
        Dim conn As New OracleConnection
        Dim cmd As New OracleCommand
        Dim adapter As New OracleDataAdapter

        Try
            conn.ConnectionString = strOracleConnection
            conn.Open()
            Exit Try
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(strMsgException & ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Erreur Connexion Bases Oracle")
            Return Nothing
            Exit Try
        End Try
    End Function
```

Here is the cryptic error i had:
*Could not load file or assembly 'System.EnterpriseServices, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. Le fichier spécifié est introuvable.*

Comment: The final part of the error translates to "The specified file can not be found." presumably referring to "System.EnterpriseServices".

Comment: My issue is not solved but i gave a try with the Oracle.ManagedDataAccess Nuget Package (https://www.nuget.org/packages/oracle.manageddataaccess/) and the same code works perfectly.

Comment: @MT0 That error will also issue if a dependency can't be found---it indicates that *a* necessary file is missing, but unfortunately it doesn't indicate *which one*.  If this issue is happening on a machine that you control, then assembly resolution logging (see the Fusion log viewer) may help track down the problem.